# How to prevent generation of xml 'nil' as is 'xsi:nil="true"' elements in a soap webservice Delphi client?

Tags: delphi, soap, soap-client, delphi-11-alexandria

Since Delphi Alexandria 11.2, I have a problem with my Delphi SOAP clients.

If, in my client side application, my field `obj.entryDate` is set to `nil` (because there is no such date), then the Delphi SOAP libraries create the following in the request:

WSDL part of the SOAP request is:

```xml
<xs:complexType name="baseArchivDokumentDTO">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="entryDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

With the SOAP client that is generated for that WSDL, Delphi generates the following in requests:

```xml
<arg0>
  <test>1</test>
  <entryDate xsi:nil="true"/>
</arg0>
```

If the element is optional (and this is, what `minOccurs="0"` means above), the Java WebService does not accept the request:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error:</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The normal behaviour should be to omit that element:

```xml
<arg0>
  <test>1</test>
</arg0>
```

There was no problem before Delphi Alexandria, I think.

How can I get back the old (normal) behavior in Delphi Alexandria?

Answer (score 0):

My fallback solution would be to comment the following two methods (CreateNilNode and TSOAPDomConv.CreateNULLNode) in the Delphi unit Soap.OPToSOAPDomConv:

```
function CreateNilNode(ParentNode: IXMLNode; const Name: InvString; const Namespace: InvString): IXMLNode;
begin
//  Result := ParentNode.AddChild(Name, Namespace);
//  Result.SetAttributeNS(SSoapNil, XMLSchemaInstNameSpace, STrue);
end;

function TSOAPDomConv.CreateNULLNode(RootNode, ParentNode: IXMLNode; const Name: InvString; UseParentNode: Boolean): IXMLNode;
//var
//  Pre: InvString;
begin
//  if not UseParentNode then
//    Result := ParentNode.AddChild(Name, '')
//  else
//    Result := ParentNode;
//  Pre := FindPrefixForURI(RootNode, Result, XMLSchemaInstNameSpace, True);
//  Result.SetAttributeNS(MakeNodeName(Pre, SSoapNIL), XMLSchemaInstNameSpace, STrue);
end;
```

This would prevent the node and the attribute 'xsi:nil="true"',
but I do not like this ugly hack (change delphi source unit), because I got to support this on my own.